# about arrays and if, meeting the quality standards

Tags: python-2.7

I am unable to use if and arrays, in the example the program should print only j, but it prints, i and j.

```
import Image
import numpy as np


a=1,2,3

if(a!=1,2,3):
    print "i"

if(a==1,2,3):
    print "j"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a is a tuple not an array,  put the parens around just the numbers i.e `if a != (1, 2, 3)` if you want to compare as tuples:

```
In [1]: a=1,2,3

In [2]: (a!=1,2,3)
Out[2]: (True, 2, 3) # a != 1 -> True so creates the tuple  (True, 2, 3)

In [3]: (a==1,2,3) 
Out[3]: (False, 2, 3) # a==1 -> False so creates the tuple (False, 2, 3)
```

You are checking `if  (True, 2, 3)` and `if (False, 2, 3)`, both are *non-empty* tuples so both ifs evaluate to True, the only way that checking a tuple with an if will evaluate to False is if the tuple was empty:

```
In [9]: bool(tuple([]))
Out[9]: False
```

Once we change the syntax, you can see it now does what you expect:

```
In [22]: if a != (1, 2, 3):
             print "i"
   ....: if a == (1,2,3):    
   ....:     print("j")
   ....:     
j
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a=1,2,3` 
your **a** becomes a tuple

```
>>> a=1,2,3
>>> a
(1, 2, 3)
```

and when you do
`a!=1,2,3`  `a!=1` evaluates to True so

```
>>> a!=1,2,3
(True, 2, 3)
```

similarly,

```
>>> a==1,2,3
(False, 2, 3)
```

and becuase non empty tuples are considered True, that is why both your **ifs** are evaluating to True.

Note: even `(False,)` this will evaluate to True

Comment: Both the sugestions helped me. The final code I wrote for finding certain pixel patern using the if conditions is bellow

Comment: import Image
import numpy as np


im = Image.open("IV. Finale (Presto).png")
row, col =  im.size 
print row, col

data = np.zeros((row*col, 5))
pixels = im.load()

for i in range(row):
    #print i
    for j in range(col):
        #print j
        r,g,b =  pixels[i,j]
        data[i*col + j,:] = r,g,b,i,j
        #if np.all((r,g,b,i,j)==(127.000,127.000,255.000,34,275)):
         #   print i
          #  print j

Comment: for i in range(row):
    #print i
    for j in range(col):
        if np.all(data[i*col + j,:]==(127.000,127.000,255.000,i,j)):
            if np.all(data[(i-1)*col + j+1,:]==(255.000,255.000,255.000,i-1,j+1)):
                if np.all(data[i*col + j+1,:]==(255.000,255.000,255.000,i,j+1)):
                    if np.all(data[(i-1)*col + j,:]==(255.000,255.000,255.000,i-1,j)):
                        C0min=j